# how to detect the mouth region using opencv?

Tags: java, opencv

im working on a face detection and i want to detect the mouth region ,, the problem is it detects 5 mouths and i do not know why, please help me here is the copy of the code

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;

public class FaceDetector {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        System.out.println("\nRunning FaceDetector");

        CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(FaceDetector.class.getResource("haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml").getPath().substring(1));
        Mat image = Highgui
                .imread(FaceDetector.class.getResource("shekhar.JPG").getPath().substring(1) );
        MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);

        System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s faces", faceDetections.toArray().length));
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a flag that can be set in the detectMultiscale function, which when set, will return the biggest detection. That should help select one of the many detections that the detector returns.

Please read the documentation if you would want to know how you can go about it.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/objdetect/CascadeClassifier.html
It's just a google search away!